# T-SQL query group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

can you help me to filter the results of the following query

```
    SELECT ProjectName = p.Code ,LotName = lp.Nom , PhaseActive = ph.Nom ,Item = l.Code, Value = c.Note, Cycle = cdv.Nom, Pole = lp.Pole, Note = lp.Note, idEdition = lp.IdEdition, c.DateCreation
                    FROM Controles c 
                    Join LotProjets lp ON c.IdLotProjet = lp.IdLotProjet
                    JOIN Projets p ON lp.IdProjet = p.IdProjet
                    JOIN Referentiels r ON c.IdReferentiel = r.IdReferentiel
                    JOIN Livrables l ON r.LivrableId = l.IdLivrable
                    JOIN Phases ph ON lp.IdPhase = ph.IdPhase 
                    JOIN CycleDeVies cdv ON ph.CycleDeVieId = cdv.IdCycleDeVie
                    WHERE lp.IdEdition = 3 AND c.DateSuppression IS NULL
```

Which gives the following result

```
#  | ProjectName | LotName | PhaseActive  | Item  | Value | Cycle | Pole | Note | idEdition | DateCreation
1  | P00935      | 06      | Fin de cycle | CVAI  | 0     | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:42:54.867
2  | P00935      | 06      | Fin de cycle | DCN-T | 100   | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:42:55.500
3  | P00935      | 06      | Fin de cycle | PTA   | 33    | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:42:58.493
4  | P00935      | 06      | Fin de cycle | DPE   | 100   | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:43:00.903
5  | P00935      | 06      | Fin de cycle | BTA   | 98    | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:43:01.617
6  | P00935      | 06      | Fin de cycle | FPH   | 72    | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:43:06.987
7  | P00935      | 06      | Fin de cycle | QSE   | 0     | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:43:10.013
8  | P00935      | 06      | Fin de cycle | DPE   | 0     | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:43:15.313
9  | P00935      | 06      | Fin de cycle | DPE   | 98    | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2017-01-11 12:13:44.660
10 | P00935      | 06      | Fin de cycle | DPE   | 77    | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2017-01-11 12:16:32.557
11 | P00935      | 05      | Fin de cycle | DPE   | 75    | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2017-01-11 12:16:32.557
```

For each Item in each LotName I would like the most recent value to have the      following result.

```
# | ProjectName| LotName | PhaseActive  | Item  | Value | Cycle | Pole | Note | idEdition | DateCreation
1 | P00935     | 06      | Fin de cycle | CVAI  | 0     | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:42:54.867
2 | P00935     | 06      | Fin de cycle | DCN-T | 100   | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:42:55.500
3 | P00935     | 06      | Fin de cycle | PTA   | 33    | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:42:58.493
4 | P00935     | 06      | Fin de cycle | DPE   | 100   | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:43:00.903
5 | P00935     | 06      | Fin de cycle | BTA   | 98    | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:43:01.617
6 | P00935     | 06      | Fin de cycle | FPH   | 72    | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:43:06.987
7 | P00935     | 06      | Fin de cycle | QSE   | 0     | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2016-12-21 13:43:10.013
8 | P00935     | 06      | Fin de cycle | DPE   | 77    | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2017-01-11 12:16:32.557
9 | P00935     | 05      | Fin de cycle | DPE   | 75    | Autre | TRV  | 47   | 3         | 2017-01-11 12:16:40.435
```

I thought I should use the GROUP BY clause but I can not find a configuration where it works. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Do `MAX(DateCreation)` and follow the general `GROUP BY` rule which says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: ...or just use a windowing function `MAX(DateCreation) OVER (ORDER BY....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition the data, number the rows in each partition, and take the rows where row number is 1:

```
with cte as (
SELECT ProjectName = p.Code ,LotName = lp.Nom , PhaseActive = ph.Nom ,Item = l.Code, Value = c.Note, Cycle = cdv.Nom, Pole = lp.Pole, Note = lp.Note, idEdition = lp.IdEdition, c.DateCreation,
row_number() over (partition by LotName, Item order by DateCreation desc) as rn
                    FROM Controles c 
                    Join LotProjets lp ON c.IdLotProjet = lp.IdLotProjet
                    JOIN Projets p ON lp.IdProjet = p.IdProjet
                    JOIN Referentiels r ON c.IdReferentiel = r.IdReferentiel
                    JOIN Livrables l ON r.LivrableId = l.IdLivrable
                    JOIN Phases ph ON lp.IdPhase = ph.IdPhase 
                    JOIN CycleDeVies cdv ON ph.CycleDeVieId = cdv.IdCycleDeVie
                    WHERE lp.IdEdition = 3 AND c.DateSuppression IS NULL
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```